# Best way to transfer data from one database to another

Tags: mysql, laravel

I re-created my database. I need to migrate it with my new architecture.

I need to migrate 500k rows, but It works too slow.
1k row, in 5 minutes. So that, 500k rows will be 50 hours.

Whats wrong with my code?

Is there any way to transfer that data to my new database with conditions below.

```
  foreach($baskets as $pr){
    $bull = Order::find($pr->orderId);
    if($bull){
      echo $pr->basketId."<br>";
    if($pr->basketPrice>0){
      $bul = Product::where('type', 'subscription')->where('former_id', $pr->productId)->first();

      $basket = new Basket;
      $basket->former_id = $pr->basketId;
      $basket->user_id = $pr->userId;
      $basket->order_id = $pr->orderId;
      $basket->is_rerun = false;
      $basket->status = 'aktif';
      $basket->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $pr->basketDate);

      $basket->product_id = $bul->id;

      $price = $pr->basketPrice;
      if($basket->total_months&&$price<100){
        $price = $pr->basketPrice*$basket->total_months;
      }
      $basket->quantity = 1;
      $basket->price = $price/1.18;
      $basket->vat = $price-($price/1.18);

      $basket->save();
    }

    $ddv = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('delivery')
    ->whereNotNull('deliveryAddress')
    ->whereNotNull('billAddress')
    ->where('basketId', $pr->basketId)->first();

    $extras = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('extra')
    ->whereNotNull('userId')
    ->whereNotNull('orderId')
    ->where('deliveryId', $ddv->deliveryId)->get();
    foreach($extras as $xt){

      $bull = Order::find($xt->orderId);
      if($bull){
      $product = new Basket;
      $product->former_id = $ddv->basketId;
      $product->former_extra_id = $xt->extraId;
      $product->user_id = $xt->userId;
      $product->order_id = $xt->orderId;
      $product->is_rerun = false;
      $product->status = 'aktif';
      $product->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $xt->extraDate);

      $product->product_id = $xt->extraProductId;

      $price = $xt->extraPrice;
      $product->quantity = $xt->extraCount;
      $product->price = $price/1.18;
      $product->vat = $price-($price/1.18);

      $product->save();
      }
    }

    
  }
  }
```

Comment: If you’re doing this row by row, then it’ll take a while. Are you able to create batch import files by writing a custom .sql dump file in the code?

Comment: write an SQL procedure. Then call the procedure from the PHP code.  Terrible idea to put business logic into PHP.

Comment: Don't use code.  Certainly don't move one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  `mysqldump | mysql`

Plan B:  `INSERT INTO new_db.tbl SELECT * FROM old_db.tbl;`

Plan C:  Might be about to move all files from one computer to another, then use `mysql_upgrade` if the version is newer.

(There are other options; need more details to judge which makes sense for your case.)